# Adding items to ObservableCollection doesn't change the ListView

Tags: c#, binding

I can't figure out why my ListView isn't updating when I add items to an observable collection. 
Here's what the UI starts as
 [image]

And here's what it looks like after I add an item
[image]

For whatever reason the ListView is not picking up the work order, nor the check in date, however it does update the TechCount...

Here's the ListView code:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding LaborItems}"      
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLaborItem}" 
        Margin="10,10,10,9">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="#" Width="55" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Labor.WorkOrderNo}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Labor.Time.CheckIn}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Techs" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TechCount}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

It's easier to see relevant code in a picture, so I'm doing a screen short instead of raw code
[image]

Line 26 is what runs when I click the + button on the UI. TechCount has a similar implementation to CheckIn, which just refers to fields within Labor.

Here's the complete viewmodel code:

```
public class ServiceItemsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Labor Labor { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Labor> LaborItems { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<Labor>();

public ServiceItemsViewModel()
{
    Labor = new Labor();
    Labor.Rates = new LaborRatesDual();
    AddLaborCommand = new DelegateCommand(addLabor, null);
}

public ICommand AddLaborCommand { get; private set; }

private void addLabor(object obj)
{
    LaborItems.Add(Labor);
    Labor = new Labor();
}

private bool canAddLabor(object arg)
{
    if (Labor.Duration.Minutes < 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //if (AdditionalBillingRate <= 0 || AdditionalPayoutRate <= 0)
    //{
    //    return false;
    //}

    return true;
}

public DateTime CheckIn
{
    get { return Labor.Time.CheckIn; }
    set
    {
        Labor.Time.CheckIn = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Labor));
    }
}
public DateTime CheckOut
{
    get { return Labor.Time.CheckOut; }
    set
    {
        Labor.Time.CheckOut = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Labor));
        ((DelegateCommand)AddLaborCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
public int TechCount
{
    get { return Labor.TechCount; }
    set
    {
        Labor.TechCount = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Labor));
    }
}
public decimal InitialPayoutRate
{
    get { return Labor.Rates.InitialPayoutRate; }
    set
    {
        Labor.Rates.InitialPayoutRate = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Labor));
        //((DelegateCommand)AddLaborCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
public decimal AdditionalPayoutRate
{
    get { return Labor.Rates.AdditionalPayoutRate; }
    set
    {
        Labor.Rates.AdditionalPayoutRate = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Labor));
        //((DelegateCommand)AddLaborCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
public decimal InitialBillingRate
{
    get { return Labor.Rates.InitialBillingRate; }
    set
    {
        Labor.Rates.InitialBillingRate = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Labor));
        //((DelegateCommand)AddLaborCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
public decimal AdditionalBillingRate
{
    get { return Labor.Rates.AdditionalBillingRate; }
    set
    {
        Labor.Rates.AdditionalBillingRate = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Labor));
        //((DelegateCommand)AddLaborCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}

private Labor selectedLaborItem;
public Labor SelectedLaborItem
{
    get { return selectedLaborItem; }
    set
    {
        selectedLaborItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Labor));
    }
}
```

Labor contents after I click the + button:
[image]

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint on line 26 and tell us what the contents of `Labor` are?

Comment: @Max added a screenshot to the main post.

Comment: Not sure, since I didn't work with WPF for some time, but could you change `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Labor.Time.CheckIn}"` to `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Labor.Time.CheckIn, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`? Perhaps one of these new properties `Mode` or `UpdateSourceTrigger` will help you with this.

Comment: @haosmark, are other bindings in the view working?

Comment: @SledgeHammer yes, they all map to a Labor object in the viewmodel just fine.

Comment: @haosmark, why are your first 2 GridViewColumn's binding to "Labor."? Looks like you're binding to the data entry view rather then the ItemsSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column bindings are wrong:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="#" Width="55" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding **Labor.**WorkOrderNo}"/>
<GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding **Labor.**Time.CheckIn}"/>
<GridViewColumn Header="Techs" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TechCount}" />
```

See asterisked areas above.

Answer (score 0):

You are already binding to a collection of Labor

```
ItemsSource="{Binding LaborItems}"
```

Labor is not a property of Labor

```
<GridViewColumn Header="#"    Width="55"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding WorkOrderNo}"/>
<GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Time.CheckIn}"/>
```